# KWGT: How to create an Android App with a collection of my own Widgets

Tags: widget, android-widget

I have created multiple KWGT widgets and want to put them together in a Android app for distribution.
I am not able to find any tutorial on YouTube or Google.
Does anyone have any tips or tutorial details?